# WF4 - Argument types limited to .NET types only?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to set a workflow argument to a custom type 'Contact' class but no matter what I try it just won't find it in the explorer. The only things I see under my namespace are the 2 names of my xaml files, App & MainWindow1

What gives? I want to pass in a Contact object and use the workflow to check a few different items then return true/false.

Comment: I can guarantee you it works.  Are you sure your types are public?  Are you sure they have default constructors?  Are you sure they are DataContracts or are serializable?  Open your compiled assembly in reflector and make sure your type is actually under the namespace you think it is with the name you think it has (make no assumptions!)

Comment: omfg, i didn't have any of my models as public. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your models public, kthx.